# LINQ querying complex many to many entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code first and I've this model

[image]

I need to get all *Id* in *InformesRecepcionFacturasEspanaC_Productos* and for each Id get all the *Id* and *Cantidad* in *AlbaranesEspanaC_Productos*.

I don't know how to write the query because I've to traverse two many to many relationships.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should include your table schema as text as it is very hard to read all the details in that picture.  You could loop through the `InformesRecepcionFacturasEspanaC_Productos` records and pull each of the records in `AlbaranesEspanaC_Productos` and save them to a `List`.

Comment: Can you post the models? It's hard to tell if you have navigation properties on these models.

Comment: You need to use a left outer join since some ids may be in one table and not the other.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to see the data, but here's one way to do it (assuming Id in the AlbaranesEspanaC_Productos table is an int and Cantidad is a string, and assuming the name of your DB context is DbContext):

```
List<int> ProductosIds = DbContext.InformesRecepcionFacturasEspanaC_Productos.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var IdAndCantidads = DbContext.AlbaranesEspanaC_Productos.where(x => ProductosIds.Contains(x.IdAlbaranesEspanaC)).Select(new { Id = x.Id, cantidad = x.Cantidad }).ToList();
```

This is return a list of anonymous type . You could also use a dictionary instead. Then you can order / group that list however you want.